# Can I access $timeout without using the DI container?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS, can I access `$timeout` without resorting to using the DI container?

**Edit:**
For those asking for "why". I am using an older version of AngularJS and want to create a utility function that will perform a digest asynchronously.

The intention being that I can place logic inside a promise `then` for execution after a digest has occurred and the UI has taken into account the model change.

I do not want client code to have to use the injector to use said function.

I wanted something like this:

**my-file.js**

```
//...

model.watchedProperty = 'new value';
// Now I want to wait for a digest to occur so that I can ensure the UI is updated before proceeding...
digestAsync(localScope)
  .then(function() {
    // continue...
  });

// ...
```

**digest-async.js**

```
function digestAsync(scope) {
  return $timeout(function() { // I don't want to have to use the injector...
            scope.$digest();
        });
}
```

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: can you explain what you want do?

Comment: `$timeout` seems to be a wrapper for the `setTimeout` built-in function-object, that is tied into the digest cycle. It seems as though this is orthogonal to the DI container, so I wondered if you could access `$timeout` directly.

Comment: @BenAston, all wrappers in angular is a services, so you can not get it without `$injector` or DI. But, you can just realize yout own $timeout with `setTimeout` and _apply_

Comment: Even after your edit I do not get what the problem with the injector is

Comment: @Grundy, okay thanks. Is writing a `digestAsync` function similar to the above (my example is pseudocode and I know will not work as-written) a valid approach to preventing further code execution until a digest has updated the UI per a changed watched model property value?

Comment: you can see [source for `$timeout`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/timeout.js)

Comment: Do you want `digestAsync` is a global function not in angular?

Comment: @Grundy. Yes. In short I want to ensure a digest has completed and the UI has updated before continuing with further logic. The `$timeout` in this instance is merely shorthand for "ensure a digest is not already in progress" (I think).

Comment: just see source for `$timeout` and [`$browser.defer`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/browser.js) that used inside, and you can create similar function

Comment: Notice that the original question still doesn't contain why exactly you want it to do that, i.e. to trigger digest outside Angular.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually get the injector and then get the `$timeout` service.

```
var $injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
var $timeout = $injector.get('$timeout');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to inject `$timeout` you can add `$injector` as a DI, and in your code you can put this:

```
$timeout = $injector.get('$timeout');
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same thing after all?

Comment: which then injects `$injector` before...it injects `$timeout`. Its the same thing, just with an additional (unnecessary) injection and at a point in the code where it is unexpected , making the code harder to read

Comment: Yes, but if you don't want to inject `$injector` as a DI, you can do this like this: `var $injector = angular.injector();`

Comment: You have all the things in here: [angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector)

Comment: The point is that that is just a very complicated way of writing the exact same thing. You are not accessing `$timeout` any more "direct" than just regularly injecting it by defining it as a dependency. It comes from the exact same place, defining it as a dependency is just a shorter (and more clear) way of doing that.

Comment: But sometimes it is necessary :/

Comment: This is known as a [service locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/), and you should avoid that most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not. A lot of angular is itself written in angular, [including `$timeout`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/timeout.js). So you can access it in any way you can access any other self-written service - by Dependency Injection

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use `$timeout` if you want the callback function to be executed inside an Angular digest cycle, and if you pass `0` as the interval then it will be executed in the next digest.

The `setTimeout` function from JS will execute the callback using the next "thread" cycle. That means that the current thread has to terminate first before the callback can be execute. That doesn't mean that the next thread cycle will also be an Angular digest.

This doesn't matter in your example because you are forcing a `$digest`, except that you should be using `$apply` and not `$digest`.

I think what you are trying to do is create a promise that resolves inside an Angular digest. That's not really the proper use for promises because a digest is not a resource to be resolved.

I think you can skip everything related to the `$timeout` and just use `$apply` as it was designed.

```
localscope.$apply(function(){
      // do digest work here
});
```

That is the same as the following.

```
$timeout(function(){
    // do digest work heere
},0);
```

Both can be executed outside of Angular, and both will execute the callback during the next digest cycle. `$apply` will call `$digest` if needed and it does state this in the documentation.

For times when you don't know if a $digest is in progress.

```
    /**
     * Executes the callback during a digest.
     *
     * @param {angular.IScope|angular.IRootScopeService} $scope
     * @param {function()} func
     */
    function safeApply($scope, func) {
        if ($scope.$$phase) {
            func();
        } else {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                func();
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks. Doing `localScope.$apply` is prone to throwing an exception if a digest is already in progress?

Comment: @BenAston, `$apply` call inside `beginPhase('$apply');` that do checking `if ($rootScope.$$phase) {
        throw $rootScopeMinErr('inprog', '{0} already in progress', $rootScope.$$phase);
      }` from [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js), `apply` can raise error if digest already in progress

Comment: @BenAston here's a helper function I always use for cases like that.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia, i not sure that checking private `$scope.$$phase` field is _best practices_. [angular wiki: anti-patterns](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Anti-Patterns): _Don't do if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply(), it means your $scope.$apply() isn't high enough in the call stack._

Comment: @Grundy absolutely agree, and if more developers followed best practices questions like this on SO wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Since you plan to use it outside the app, there is zero chance that you will stumble upon infamous ['$digest already in progress'](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog) error. Why? Because $digest isn't asynchronous process, more like the opposite of it. All that `$digest()` function does [is calculating current scope state in loop](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.7/src/ng/rootScope.js#L745) - no promises, no timeouts.

That's exactly what

> Don't do if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply(), it means your
>   $scope.$apply() isn't high enough in the call stack.

[well-known statement](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Anti-Patterns) refers to. The only time when 'already in progress' will happen is when $digest is triggered during $digest or within `$apply`, e.g. when outer JS function is used as Angular callback. This indicates poor application design and should be treated accordingly.

Thereby `$digest` function can be exposed to `window`

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    window.$digest = angular.bind($rootScope, $rootScope.$digest);
});
```

And used in synchronous manner. No promises. No timeouts.

```
model.watchedProperty = 'new value';
$digest();
// 'watchedProperty' watcher has been digested ATM
```

And I assume that you already know why mixing Angular and outer code like that is considered a bad practice and should be avoided.